# Authorization on executing query on Progress OpenEdge with C#

Tags: c#, database-administration, openedge, progress-4gl, progress-db

I have performed all the processes for installing and configuring the Progress OpenEdge version 11.7 database. I configured the DSN with username and password and to access the database I created and everything connected correctly.

After performing the connection to the database, I get the following error message when executing a query to get data:

**Error:**
ERROR [HY000] [DataDirect][ODBC Progress OpenEdge Wire Protocol driver][OPENEDGE]Access denied (Authorization failed) (7512)

I have accessed OpenEdge Management to guarantee all permissions for my user as shown below, but I still get this error message.

[image]

**Code:**

```
public static bool InsertItem(string itCodigo, string descItem, string um)
    {
        bool ret = false;
        string connectString = "DSN=DSN-Name;uid=renan;pwd=*****;host=localhost;port=XXXX;db=DatabaseName;";

        using (OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(connectString))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                IDbCommand dbcmd = connection.CreateCommand();
                string sqlstr = "select * from Hipolabor.pub.Item";
                dbcmd.CommandText = sqlstr;

                using (IDataReader rdr = dbcmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    var b = rdr.Read();                        
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
        return ret;
    }
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The permissions that you are showing from "data administration" are 4gl permissions.  The 4gl and SQL-92 engines do not share permissions.

If nothing else has been done the initial SQL dba is the user who created the db.  Depending on what version of Progress this is and how this database was setup and created you might also have a "sysprogress" user defined who might be the system DBA user.

The "renan" user id may not be a SQL user -- that also depends on the Progress version how this db has been setup.

Comment: Actually, I had created the database and only then created a new user and assigned the permissions to this user.

So should I create a new database with the user 'renan' so I can access and perform the operations?

Comment: It should be sufficient to login using a sql tool such as “sqlexp” as whoever actually created the db (or sysprogress) and grant permissions.